# How to build generated and executable jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have a directory in which I generated *.class files. How can I build executable jar file from this files.

What I need to know is

- how to clean dir
- how to put all files in jar and make it executable

Sorry people i didnt mentioned, i need do this programmatically in java code.

Comment: Are you using any IDE like eclipse? If you are using, you can export the classes as executable jar while specifying one main class as entrant.

Comment: Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java cfe myJar.jar Classname.class myClass
```

and for exceution

```
java -jar Jarname.jar
```

Creating a [Jar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: Dang it beat me to it. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans, there are specific easier ways to do it. If not I think the following command would work:
`jar cfe <jar-file> <main-class-name> <class-files...>`